# Need help focusing on previous element on screen when inside Input field

Tags: javascript, html

We're currently working on developing a new blog look & feel and stumbled upon an accessibility issue that is popping up.

https://test.webservices.illinois.edu/blog/view/6186

When you tab through the page and get to the Archive link, it lights up red (correct), then if you tab again, you enter the search input field.  If you try to go back (SHIFT + TAB), you don't leave the input field (it continues blinking) and don't get to the Archive link.

Any idea what's causing it?

Comment: The link you provided requires authentication. Can you isolate your problem into a jsbin/stackoverflow snippet so we can better help you?

Comment: Do you have `keydown` event handler assigned to the field? Make sure you are not doing `event.preventDefault();` within handler's function. If so, check which keys are being pressed.

Comment: It should be working correctly now, I hope.  Had to change security settings.